# What is the proper terminology for "I touch" in this sentence?

Tags: syntax, grammar, syntax-trees, parts-of-speech

I am trying to diagram this sentence for a personal project:

> Everything I touch with tenderness pricks like a bramble.

From what I understand, **Everything** is the subject, and **pricks** is the predicate with **like a bramble** being an adverbial phrase modifying pricks. I cannot tell what **I touch**'s place is in this all, however. I think it is modifying **Everything**, but I don't know how to classify it.

Comment: It's a relative clause: try analyzing it with "everything *that* I touch" instead, then just say the "that" is invisible.

Comment: @Draconis, that should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's tripping you up is a relative clause with an "invisible relative adjective".

First, start with your outer sentence:

> Everything pricks like a bramble.

Come up with a diagram of this, using whatever theory you prefer.

Now look at the first part again:

> Everything [that] I touch with tenderness…

The relative clause seems to be a sentence of its own!

> …I touch [that] with tenderness…

So this is a sentence (an S or a TP or an IP or whatever your theory calls it), embedded into an adjectival phrase, which modifies the noun "everything".

Comment: Thank you! I could tell that it was complete and modifying **Everything**, but I just didn't really know how to describe it. I'll mark as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

"I touch" is nothing, that is, it is not a unit of linguistic analysis. "I" is a subject / pronoun and "touch" is a verb"; the two words are part of a relative clause "I touch with tenderness". Actually, it is a sentence, which in this context functions as a relative clause. That relative clause is modifying something – the word "Everything".

Comment: Hmmm. It's not a sentence. It has a gap in it!